# Events in Universal Analytics isn't recording the events properly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am working on an SPA and am creating an object of Universal Analytics using the following code (The variable `analyticsId` has the analytics id for my application)

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', analyticsId, {'name': 'pnanalyze'});
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('pnanalyze.send', 'pageview');
```

This works fine.

However, I'm also using this analytics object to record custom events as follows

```
ga('pnanalyze.send', {
  'hitType': 'event',
  'eventCategory': 'product',
  'eventAction': 'view',
  'eventLabel': 'DEFAULT'
});
```

This event is not getting recorded. I can see that the request is being made with all the proper parameters (or so I think) but the event is not showing up in my reporting widgets.

Can someone please tell me what the issue is here?

The query string parameters for the ga request for this particular hit are:

```
v:1
_v:j24
a:1179576437
t:event
_s:4
dl:http://localhost/p/5369dac10364f6a73daad096
ul:en-us
de:UTF-8
dt:ProdNote
sd:24-bit
sr:1280x800
vp:1280x595
je:1
fl:14.0 r0
ec:product
ea:view
el:DEFAULT
ev:53e355920364fbe1bfd0392d
_u:OACAAAQ~
cid:1040154947.1404805392
tid:UA-52638266-2
z:778670853
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct, and the 'pnanalyze' tracker name should not matter - you can leave it in (I tested on my own page and I can see data in GA). Keep in mind that once you start using a tracker name, you must stick with it. Are you checking in your Real-time reports to see if the event gets tracked? It won't show up in your standard report view for another 24-48 hours.

Comment: Yes, I did check the real-time reports. The events are not getting recorded there. And as you mentioned I'm using the tracker name (pnanalyze) throughout the application for recording pageviews and events. The pageviews seems to be working fine. The events however aren't :(

Comment: Are you seeing your events in the RealTime reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out, the issue was because I was passing a alphanumeric value for the `eventValue` property. I did not add that bit here as I did not in the least bit anticipate that THAT could cause this issue.

Making sure that I pass numeric values should fixed this issue, although to be on the safer side I'm doing away with the `eventValue` field altogether. :P

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, you're just trying to pass an event when a pageview happens on a product page?

I think that GA doesn't understand the *pnanalyze.send* - try passing this:

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',
  'eventCategory': 'product',
  'eventAction': 'view',
  'eventLabel': 'DEFAULT'
});`
```

Then if you want to have it show up at certain products, create an IF statement around it.

Also, as a precautionary (and even though it's working), I would take the *pnanalyze.send* out of

```
ga('pnanalyze.send', 'pageview');
```

Since GA uses this to send information back to your account.